# Replacement of MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I wan to replace an old mysql statement with new one. Does anyone know me if the following replacement concept is correct?

The following statement

```
$people = mysql_query("SELECT`id`,`full_name` FROM prople WHERE id > '0'") or die (mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_num_row($people);

if ( $result > 0 ) { 
list($id, $full_name) = mysql_fetch_row($people);
```

shall be replaced by:

```
mysql_select_db($database_xx, $yy);
$query_people = "SELECT`id`,`full_name` FROM prople WHERE id > '0'";
$people  = mysql_query($query_people, $yy) or die (mysql_error());
$row_people  = mysql_fetch_row($people);
$totalRows_people = mysql_num_rows($people );

if ( $totalRows_people > 0 ) { 
list($id,$full_name) = mysql_fetch_row($people);
```

Is the above replacement correct?

Comment: If you are changing out your code, why not change to get rid of deprecated `mysql_*` functions in favor of `mysqli` or `PDO`? That being said, I don't follow your logic in either case.  In the first example, you only get one row of data.  In the second you fetch a row of data, then try to look at the row count, then fetch a second row of data.  Neither case would allow you to iterate over a full multi-row result set.

Comment: ^ this. It looks like all you did is change up the name of variables. Why not replace it with better code instead of more complicated code :p

Comment: @ Mike Brant , of course i shall upgrade my codes to `PDO` but before that i want to learn more details about `MySql`.

Comment: If you're still in the "learning phase", ditch all `mysql_*` functions now!

Comment: @SilentPond Why? It is deprecated.  Just learn the right way with either `mysqli` (which can be used procedurally much like `mysql`) or `PDO`. Honestly, I would also recommend working in an object-oriented manner rather than a procedural one, but that is not as important IMO as simply dumping the approach of using `mysql_*`

Comment: @Half Crazed & @Mike Brant  , web things are my hobby. it's not my occupation. in order to switch to `PDO` i shall require enormous time and unfortunately i haven't much time after my hobby than my occupation. may be i shall be learning `pdo` in the future within this limitation.

Comment: @SilentPond OK well. You are basically asking for a code review, which is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ anyway.  Your logic still doesn't seem to make sense in either case.

Comment: This question is, in essence, a code review better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mike Brant , thanks for the reference. my be i shall post my question there. the most important thing is that learning unfamiliar or brand new codes requires enough concentration. unfortunately i have no ability to put that much concentration for learning new codes. at this moment my occupation is important to me as you may realize that we can't bypass our livelyhood. interesting thing is that my hobby is partially related to my livelyhood. thanks again.

Comment: @Half Crazed , i wish i could learn mysql_* functions on the way like i'm now. ty.